# Interrupt a thread from another thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to create a program that simulate a bomb... The user has 5 seconds to digit the right code, if he can't, the bomb explodes.

```
class Codice implements Runnable{
String code;
@Override
public void run() {
    code = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Inserire codice disinnesco:");
    if(code.equals(Bomba.check)) {
        Bomba.s = "true";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bomba disinnescata");
    }
    System.out.println(Bomba.s);
}
}

class Esplosione implements Runnable{
@Override
public void run() {
    
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(!Bomba.s.equals("true")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "BOOM!");
    }
}
}
public class Bomba {
static String s = "false";
static String check = "123456";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Codice c = new Codice();
    Esplosione ex = new Esplosione();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(c);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(ex);
    
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
}
```

With this code i can insert the code, and if it's right the bomb doesn't explodes and the program finish. If 5 seconds passes, the message "boom" appears but the first thread doeasn't stop... How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to coordinate between threads; interrupting is one way. Here is an example using `Thread.interrupt`. It dispenses with your state variable `s`, which becomes unnecessary:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

class Codice implements Runnable {
    String code;
    Thread other;

    Codice(Thread other) {
        this.other = other;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        code = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Inserire codice disinnesco:");
        if(code.equals(Bomba.check)) {
            other.interrupt();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bomba disinnescata");
        }
    }
}
    
class Esplosione implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {     
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "BOOM!");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class Bomba {
    static String check = "123456";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Esplosione ex = new Esplosione();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(ex);
        Codice c = new Codice(t2);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(c);
        
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```